# How to deny the Multi-Window feature?

Tags: java, android, multi-window

I want to deny this option on my app.

I already tried to use this guys in `manifest`->`application`:

```
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:resizeableActivity="false"
```

But I still can resize my app with my mobile.

May be it is mobile's own feature. By the way, I found some system apps with really denied resizing. `Camera` - for example. If you just try to resize this app, it is escapes with message: "app does not support the multi-window mode".

Comment: What is your target API level? android:resizeableActivity property requires target API level 24 or later.

Comment: @fthdgn I have `minSdkVersion=14` and `targetSdkVersion=28`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this

```
android:resizeableActivity="false"
```

in each activity in your manfiest so it will look like

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:resizeableActivity="false" />
```

Comment: It is not required to add it all activities. It can be added to Application. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window